# How to invert QImage without affecting performance?

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qimage

I have a QImage in a QGraphicsView which I need to show images continously. Some times I need to show the inverted images continuously. For this I use

```
img.invertPixels(QImage::InvertRgba);
```

But at this time, the display is flickering due to the continuous inverting process. How can I implement the inverting process without affecting the performance? The display seems to be smooth without invert. `

```
QImage img(byImageBuf, width, height, QImage::Format_Indexed8);   
  scene->clear();        
 if(bInvertPixel)       
 {   
    /* Inverted image */        
     img.invertPixels(QImage::InvertRgba);      
 }        
 scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));     

 view->fitInView(0, 0, width, height,  Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);        
 view->update();`
```

Comment: What do you mean by "invert image without affecting the performance"? Do you imagine that images can be inverted without CPU cycles?

Comment: invert means changing black to white and white to black

Comment: I was asking about the "without affecting the performance" part. What makes you think that `img.invertPixels(QImage::InvertRgba);` is not already as fast as it gets?

Comment: When I display the image continously without inverting, it shows it in a smoothen manner, but while inverting, the display is flickering.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very vague and unclear. I suggest you edit it a bit. Make sure you describe clearly what your doing, and what the problem is. For example, why didn't you say 'flicker' in the first place. How do you expect anyone to guess that 'affecting the performance' means 'flicker'?

Comment: question edited. Please help

Comment: Still not clear enough. Try adding the code that produces the flicker. And you don't need to add 'Please help' :)

Comment: Your source code is incomplete. What is the shown code wrapped in? Is it a callback? A slot? An infinite loop? To me it sounds like an infinite loop that gets called continuously.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using an indexed image type (`QImage::Format_Indexed8`) you can invert the color table and just toggle that:

```
if(bInvertPixel)
{
   /* Inverted image */
   img.setColorTable( invertedColorTable );
}
else
{
   img.setColorTable( standardColorTable );
}
```

`standardColorTable` and `invertedColorTable` are arrays of QRgb values.

The beauty of the color table is that you do not have to update it every time you display your image; just set it once and forget about it.  Connect a signal from a button for inverting the colors and set the color table there.